# How can I version my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, webserver, versioning

I am sure there are a number of strategies in doing this, but I am fairly weak in my understanding of how webservers process things and how to handle this is general.

We have an asp.net webforms site with a sql server backend. What we would like to accomplish is as we update the site to, lets say version 1.5, we would like to keep all of our current clients looking at the 1.0 code until we roll out a database update for them. Once the database is updated, then they would point to the new version.

Is there a fairly simple way to accomplish this? The model we have is we have the website hosted, but all their databases are local. I have thought about maybe having a couple of different web servers and cycle through each one like this:

ServerA - version 1

ServerB - version 2

ServerC - version 3

And then once we get to version for, maybe overwrite version 1 and continue to loop through them that way? This is why I mentioned I am server/hardware challenged because this idea might be laughable to those with knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple websites on the same server, just use different ports,

- site 1 is server:81
- site 2 is server:82
- site 3 is server:83

etc. and set up multiple catalogs on your database, one for each site

Comment: This is a pretty good idea. Not sure how to go about implementation, but that can be worked out as I go. I am just wanting to figure out a high level strategy for now.